# pass the value of mysql to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to select from a list of data and display the result of the selected data in a modal popup. i just can't figure out how to pass the id to the popup so i can display the result. HELP!!

```
<td> <button class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php $id= $row['id'] ?>" data-target="#myModal"  <?php echo"id=$row[id]'";?> >
          View Details
       </button>
 </td>
```

the modal popup

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Requisition Details</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <?php
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        include('mysql_connect.php');
                        $query11 =  mysql_query ("select * from p_requisition where id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
                        $rows= mysql_fetch_array($query11);
                        echo $rows['details'];
                  ?>                                       
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
           </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: you are using `$_GET`, are you submitting form on click of button??

Comment: I want to display the details of the id in a modal popup. Not familiar with jquery. been trying all sort to see what works

Comment: you ajax for this, on click, call ajax file, get data from database and display in popup

Comment: could you help me with the syntax?

Comment: check the answer, it might help you.

Comment: thanks.. do i need to pass any value to the modal popup?

Comment: just check the answer,in that i have give.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91867/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-anelka).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add class to button may be `get-data`,

then in jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".get-data"function(){
       var val = $(this).attr("data-id");    
       $.ajax({
            url: "path to ajax file",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
               $('.modal-body').html(data);          
           }
         }); 

     });
});
```

in ajax file,write query to fetch data from mysql, manipulate the data and display in popup.

`ajax.php`

```
<?php
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     include('mysql_connect.php');
     $query11 =  mysql_query ("select * from p_requisition where id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
     $rows= mysql_fetch_array($query11);
     echo $rows['details'];// here you need to manipulate the database data with html and pass it on to popup.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ajax call, when open modal like this:

**Your modal:**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Requisition Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**Your button:**

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-target="#myModal" id="myButton">
  View Details
</button>
```

**When click the button, show the modal:**

```js
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
```

**If the modal shown, you pass the data with ajax**

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: {
      dataId: $('#myModal').attr('data-id')
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $('.modal-body', '#myModal').html(data);

    }
  });
})
```

**Your getData.php like this**

```
<?php
//dataId comes from ajax (POST)
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataId');
include('mysql_connect.php');
$query11 = mysql_query("select * from p_requisition where id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query11);
//you should use json_encode, and you can parse when get back data in ajax
echo json_encode($rows['details']);
```

Comment: Thanks but am i not suppose to pass the value of the getData.php to the modal popup?

Comment: Have you error message? Tried to debug in chrome network panel?

Comment: If you open the getdata.php do you see something?

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
<td> 
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick='openModel(<?php echo"id=$row[id]";?>') >View Details</button>
  </td>
```

open your model like

```
  <script>
   function openModel(modelId,rowId){       
       $('#'+modelId).model('open');
       //Ajax call to get data for speciefic id
    }
    </script>
```